# Increment state by 1 unless current state matches or is greater than max value using setInterval

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, setinterval

I want to increment ++1 on the current state to produce an animation 'effect'. 
It does this by setInterval. I want this to stop when the state matches the maxValue.

Currently, it setStates and jumps to the value apparently skipping the incrementation.

I have tried rearranging this function. I have setting variables at different points.

What I am finding is the newMax is not taking the currentStates year. I am not sure if this is the case and it is a little confusing for me. So if we can pick through this and try to achieve an end result.

```
    yearOnChange = e => {
        const newMax = Object.values(this.state.locationData[0].year)[0] / 100000;
        const currentYear = e.currentTarget.value;
        console.log('newMax', newMax, 'currentYear', currentYear)
        const startInterval = () => window.setInterval(incrementScale, 10);
        const cancelInterval = () => window.clearTimeout(startInterval);
        const incrementScale = () => {
            if (this.state.elevationScale > newMax) {
                return cancelInterval();
            }
            return this.setState(prevState => ({
                year: currentYear,
                elevationScale: prevState.elevationScale + 1
            }));
        };
        startInterval();
    };
```

dataSet snippet/extract

```
[  {
        "location": "City of London",
        "postcode": "EC1A 7BE",
        "year": {
            "10": "464436",
            "11": "442413",
            "12": "525723",
            "13": "465451",
            "14": "625001",
            "15": "783667",
            "16": "736788",
            "17": "820305",
            "18": "802129",
            "19": "864034",
            "95": "91449",
            "96": "108999",
            "97": "116343",
            "98": "124382",
            "99": "149143",
            "00": "173738",
            "01": "284262",
            "02": "344239",
            "03": "261645",
            "04": "326913",
            "05": "330363",
            "06": "316121",
            "07": "360923",
            "08": "471861",
            "09": "400317"
        },
        "longitude": -0.100404,
        "latitude": 51.51775
    },
    {
        "location": "Barking & Dagenham",
        "postcode": "RM9 4TP",
        "year": {
            "10": "162905",
            "11": "163821",
            "12": "163899",
            "13": "167919",
            "14": "184884",
            "15": "220070",
            "16": "258758",
            "17": "282441",
            "18": "291548",
            "19": "298333",
            "95": "50460",
            "96": "50828",
            "97": "54459",
            "98": "57559",
            "99": "64532",
            "00": "71079",
            "01": "82343",
            "02": "98713",
            "03": "134750",
            "04": "150115",
            "05": "164484",
            "06": "162340",
            "07": "176577",
            "08": "194235",
            "09": "166798"
        },
        "longitude": 0.127884,
        "latitude": 51.539774
    }
]
```

When the yearOnChange function is fired. If the current elevationScale state is not the same as the newMax, increment by 1 on the setInterval recursively until it reaches the newMax, then clear the setInterval.

happy to edit this question if I've missed any details that make this confusing.

Comment: What is the value of `newMax` if you log it?

Comment: You're using arrow functions, so `this` won't be set when any of the functions are invoked.

Comment: If i refer to them with 'this', my linter throws an error and says that variable (arrow function) has been declared but never read.
 
@Pointy

What would you suggest?

Comment: Bear in mind I am using arrow functions to keep to the standard for react (that I know of)

Comment: @ApplePearPerson the value is `4.64436`, this does not change. So it stays as this value `  "10": "464436",` from the first `year` object

Comment: @davidmitten well I'm not a React user, which here means that I can't guess the context in which that `yearOnChange()` function is declared. My point was that whatever that context is will determine the value of `this` inside it and any local arrow function inside it.

Comment: As far as Im aware, `this` refers to the class that function sits in. Class extends the react apis React.Component. @Pointy

Comment: The *class* or an *instance* of the class? (I suspect it's an instance, but again I don't use React.)

Comment: I'm presuming instance in this case.

Comment: @Pointy they are [class properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties), which is experimental, in babel i believe

Answer (score 0):

@davidmitten. Just created a sample from your code. I made some edits for type conversions and some state management. See it this can help. And setting the interval reference on the component  to clear the interval.

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    elevationScale: 0,
    locationData: [

      {
        location: "City of London",
        postcode: "EC1A 7BE",
        year: {
          "10": "464436",
          "11": "442413",
          "12": "525723",
          "13": "465451",
          "14": "625001",
          "15": "783667",
          "16": "736788",
          "17": "820305",
          "18": "802129",
          "19": "864034",
          "95": "91449",
          "96": "108999",
          "97": "116343",
          "98": "124382",
          "99": "149143",
          "00": "173738",
          "01": "284262",
          "02": "344239",
          "03": "261645",
          "04": "326913",
          "05": "330363",
          "06": "316121",
          "07": "360923",
          "08": "471861",
          "09": "400317"
        },
        longitude: -0.100404,
        latitude: 51.51775
      },
      {
        location: "Barking & Dagenham",
        postcode: "RM9 4TP",
        year: {
          "10": "162905",
          "11": "163821",
          "12": "163899",
          "13": "167919",
          "14": "184884",
          "15": "220070",
          "16": "258758",
          "17": "282441",
          "18": "291548",
          "19": "298333",
          "95": "50460",
          "96": "50828",
          "97": "54459",
          "98": "57559",
          "99": "64532",
          "00": "71079",
          "01": "82343",
          "02": "98713",
          "03": "134750",
          "04": "150115",
          "05": "164484",
          "06": "162340",
          "07": "176577",
          "08": "194235",
          "09": "166798"
        },
        longitude: 0.127884,
        latitude: 51.539774
      }
    ]
  }

  yearOnChange = e => {
    const newMax = Number.parseInt(Object.values(this.state.locationData[0].year)[0]) / 100000;
    const currentYear = e.currentTarget.value;
    console.log("newMax", newMax, "currentYear", currentYear);
    const startInterval = () => {
      this.startInterval = setInterval(incrementScale, 1000);
    }   
    const cancelInterval = () => clearInterval(this.startInterval);
    const incrementScale = () => {
      console.log("Starting timer");
      console.log(this.state.elevationScale, newMax);
      if (
        this.state.elevationScale >
        Number.parseInt(Object.values(this.state.locationData[0].year)[0]) / 100000
      ) {
        cancelInterval();
      } else{
        console.log("Inside elevation scale");
        this.setState({
          year: currentYear,
          elevationScale: this.state.elevationScale + 1
        });
      }
    };
    startInterval();
  };

  render() {
    console.log("Rendering");
    return <button onClick={(e) => this.yearOnChange(e)}>Start</button>
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I've created this sandbox with more info that might help @nithin You will have to fiddle a little bit to get this working but I believe we are getting there . #GOTEAM

Comment: I don't see the sandbox link :)

Comment: that's becuase it's not there!!! -_- sorry!!!! haha

https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-hypatia-fisel?fontsize=14

Comment: What should be the value of newMax each time the year is changed? It stays constant here. So the timer doesn't increment at all once it reached the newMax

Comment: The newMac should take the value of the key. That key should be input by the year selector.

Comment: The new max in your case is a constant. Please check console log at https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rjvgws. Start from year 2001 to 1995. You should be able to see the elevation scale moving up to 95